# Im lost please help

Tags: boot, system-installation

So I removed my USB, and it crashed it is now continuously typing ext4-fs error device sbd5 ext4 find entry 1531 and system `journald` 252 failed to write entry 22 items 769 bytes ignoring read-only file system.

The issue I was having was I installed ubuntu on the erase disk settings because after my attempt with installing ubuntu with `unetbootin` where I tried to install it to `dev/sad3 ext4`  I was met with an error saying ext4 file system creation in the partition and my pc wouldn't load past the windows booter after turning it off, upon restart of my attempt with the USB after it finished installing it loaded into windows booter and wouldn't load anything.

I restarted my pc again and pressed f12 to boot from USB and it eventually allowed me to log in for the first time after about 30 minutes of staying on a blank screen eventually the ubuntu booter appeared, and numbers started flashing across my screen faster than I could read them. Eventually, I was able to reach the login screen and was successfully able to log in. I assumed it worked and it was safe to remove my USB, then my pc crashed. Is it possible for me to get my computer to boot ubuntu without the USB stick?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have installed Ubuntu *onto* the USB device. As a result, when you pull it out from the computer, the system becomes instantly unstable and crashes. It will be difficult to diagnose without a bit more knowledge of how you configured your machine.

Comment: Ok I went to files and looked at "other locations" where it says computer its showing the same amount of gb my flash drive should have so your right. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: There are many line highlighting *Read-only file system* which means either you mounted it RO and are now trying to write to it, or more likely, it was RW until an error was discovered, and it gets flipped RO to prevent data loss.  You need to `fsck` or file-system check the RO file-system.   Your question is rather hard to read without white-space.

Comment: Sorry I'm not that tech savvy so its hard for me to articulate these kinds of things. I was told to try sudo grub-install /dev/sda in the terminal and now its installing.

Comment: So yeah I think I made a boot drive by accident because I used rufus is there a way to transfer it to my computer